Alicat Mass Flow controller setup MCS-1SLPM-D-MODTCPIP-PCA14
I am currently working on a MFC from Alicat using Pymodbus, and I keep encountering this error:
Successfully connected to the Modbus server
Reading Mass Flow from address 1209
Unexpected number of registers received at address 1209. Expected 2, got 0
Failed to read Mass Flow from address 1209
Reading Device Status from address 1201
Unexpected number of registers received at address 1201. Expected 2, got 0
Failed to read Device Status from address 1201
Reading Pressure from address 1203
Unexpected number of registers received at address 1203. Expected 2, got 0
Failed to read Pressure from address 1203
Reading Temperature from address 1205
Unexpected number of registers received at address 1205. Expected 2, got 0
Failed to read Temperature from address 1205
Reading Volumetric Flow from address 1207
Unexpected number of registers received at address 1207. Expected 2, got 0
Failed to read Volumetric Flow from address 1207

I am using the provided data from the Bulletin, and I'm still getting this error.
This is the code I'm using to troubleshoot(I've taken off the IP address of the MFC):
from pymodbus.client import ModbusTcpClient
from pymodbus.exceptions import ModbusException
import time

def read_registers(client, address, count=2):
    try:
        response = client.read_holding_registers(address, count, unit=1)
        if not hasattr(response, 'registers'):
            print(f"Error reading registers at address {address}: {response}")
            return None
        if len(response.registers) != count:
            print(f"Unexpected number of registers received at address {address}. Expected {count}, got {len(response.registers)}")
            return None
        return response.registers
    except ModbusException as e:
        print(f"ModbusException reading registers at address {address}: {e}")
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"General Exception reading registers at address {address}: {e}")
        return None

def main():
    client = ModbusTcpClient('')  # Replace with your MFC IP address
    if not client.connect():
        print("Unable to connect to the Modbus server")
        return
    else:
        print("Successfully connected to the Modbus server")

    addresses = {
        'mass_flow': 1209,
        'device_status': 1201,
        'pressure': 1203,
        'temperature': 1205,
        'volumetric_flow': 1207
    }

    while True:
        for name, address in addresses.items():
            print(f"Reading {name.replace('_', ' ').title()} from address {address}")
            registers = read_registers(client, address)
            if registers is not None:
                print(f"{name.replace('_', ' ').title()}: {registers}")
            else:
                print(f"Failed to read {name.replace('_', ' ').title()} from address {address}")

        time.sleep(10)

    client.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I tried going over the manual and other sources to find the registers, but they are all the same.
